# Elastic agent installation: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to install the Elastic agent using the following command (as I do not want the publish our token here, I write "OMITTED" instead of the token):

`sudo ./elastic-agent install --url=https://172.16.201.8:443 --enrollment-token=OMITTED --insecure`

But the result is as follows:

```
Error: fail to enroll: fail to execute request to fleet-server: could not decode the response, raw response: <html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also see here in the screenshot:

[Installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAIrE.jpg)

In our environment, all the traffic is routed through a proxy. 172.16.201.8 is an exception. This is why we have inserted the following command into /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh file:

`no_proxy=172.16.201.8`

If I execute `curl --ipv4 -v "https://172.16.201.8"` , it also seems the proxy is skipped, as intended, and 172.16.201.8 can be reached:

[172.16.201.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9yLl.jpg)

I spent a lot of time to search for a solution, but did not find any. Does anyone have an idea how to troubleshoot here? Any hints would be highly appreciated!